# RStudio won't detect git. Running macOS Sierra 10.12 and latest build of git

Tags: r, git, github, version-control, rstudio

In spite of executing several methods and steps, RStudio in my machine still won't detect git and I need to push some of my projects so they remain secure and tracked. I've already made a repository in my github account and cloned it in my main local git folder but I don't see any git interface in RStudio. These are the steps I've done so far:

- Enable svn/git interface through RStudio settings. The path to git executable was wrong so I set it up to `usr/bin/git`. The executable for svn is still `usr/bin/svn` so that is fine.
- Installed latest build of git 2.10.1 for mac. When running `which git` in Terminal, the console provides me with the executable path which of course means git is there and ready.
- Restarted Rstudio after doing these operations, and still there won't be any git interface.
- RStudio doesn't ask if a new project needs to be a git repository in *File>New Project>Empty Directory*. All I see is standard interface.
- Choosing Git under *File>New Project>Version Control* gives me an error that git hasn't been detected under the existing path `usr/bin/git` when the same is reproduced by the Terminal.
- Unchecking and checking git interface under global options and restarting RStudio does nothing. Under project options, there is no 'git' under version control menu.
- Checked if existing directories are git repositories and they are. Should be automatically getting git interface then.

I'm running a MBP 2013, macOS 10.12 with R 3.3.2 'Sincere Pumpkin Patch' and RStudio 1.0.136. Do I need to update any packages? I also have the github client AND SourceTree client installed (using the latter) and almost forgot, I have also configured git with my username and email in the shell command and there seems to be no problems as far as those settings are concerned. Is there anything else missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set **Git/SVN** interface like below:
[image]

The paths for git and svn are the directories which they installed. But you use `usr/bin/git` and `usr/bin/svn` instead.

Comment: You didn't read the full problem. I've clearly mentioned in my post that I'm running a MacBook with macOS 12.10. There are no C or D drives here. And the path to executables mentioned by me is the exact path that needs to be for mac machines.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. I just give the screen shot for your reference: it's the path which git and svn installed. You use `usr/bin/git` and `usr/bin/svn`, but git and svn can't be installed to `usr/bin` at the same time.

Comment: Ok. But I found both the executables in the `/bin/` folder. The `svn` executable is present by default.

Comment: Yes, git and svn should be in `bin/` folde, but you should set the full path in RStudio. Such as git executable path is `/Users/a/git/bin/git.exe` and svn executable path is `/Users/a/subversion/bin/svn.exe`. The full path for them should be different.

Comment: Thanks for that insight! I'll look into this and revert back.

Comment: Got Solved! You were right, the full path to git was missing and this went utterly unnoticed by me :P I see git interface now. Many thanks!!